# How to make entries for a cancellation fee & return in GnuCash

Tags: gnucash

I have booked some flight tickets using Debit Card and then later had to cancel them. I received part of the money after cancellation fee is deducted. What is a good way to record **this type of transactions** in GnuCash?

Sample Transaction in chronological order is as follows:

```
1.Bank Acc---->Expense:Flight_Ticket: 1000 USD
2.Bank Acc Received 700 USD After 'Cancellation fee' of 300USD
```

---

This is for my personal finance tracking. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is to just ***credit*** the difference between the cancellation fee and the original flight from the same expense account that the 'Expense:Flight_Ticket' was charged to:

```
Bank Acc----> Expense:Flight_Ticket: 700 Credit (refund sans cancel fee)
```

If you need or want to account for 'cancellation fees' independently from flight expenses, you can create a separate expense account for them.  Then create a split as follows:

```
Bank Acc --->Expense:Flight_Ticket: 1000 Credit 
    Expense:Cancellation Fee: 300 Debit
```

Which will result in a net increase of $700 to your bank account.